# Handling optional parameters in a servlet

Tags: java, null, servlets

I have a form that submits to a servlet that has optional parameters. If they are empty they are just ignored. This is the template I am using:

```
if (!(param = (String)params.get("httpParam")).equals("")) {
   // Handle parameter
}
```

It doesn't quite feel right. It *works*, but I think it could be more readable. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest extract code for getting parameter to separate method (see [extract method](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/extract-method) refactoring's tehnique):

```
param = getOptionalParameter("httpParam");
if (! param.isEmpty()) {
    // Handle parameter
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can populate a map containing all your parameters and than convert that map into POJO:

```
    HashMap map = new HashMap();
    Enumeration names = request.getParameterNames();
    while (names.hasMoreElements()) {
      String name = (String) names.nextElement();
      map.put(name, request.getParameterValues(name));
    }
    BeanUtils.populate(data, map);
```

Where 'data' is your POJO class with attributes corresponding to your parameter names.

Comment: How about request.getParameterMap() instead of while loop?